# Trim part of date field to perform a count and group by query

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
EnteredDate              Item

1/2/2014 12:01:59 PM.    Bags

1/2/2014 12:02:54 PM.    Bags

1/3/2014 12:04:55 pm.    Shoes
```

I want to return a count of

```
1/2/2014 Bags  2
1/3/2014 Shoes 1
```

I can do the select and count query but because my data is stored in long date format I can,t group by date unless I trim the time part. Can that be done in SQL query?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select cast(entereddate as date), item, count(*)
from table1
group by cast(entereddate as date), item
```

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/510a7/5)

Comment: @KenWhite Yeah, I forgot the item field, I've update it now. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: No, your edit went through right after I posted my comment. (That's why the comment is gone now.) I also upvoted the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer may depend on the flavor of SQL you are using, but try this:

```
Select Item,
       DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, EnteredDate), 0) as EnteredDate,
       Count(*) As ItemCount
From   YourTableNameHere
Group By Item, 
         DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, EnteredDate), 0)
```

All of that DateAdd and DateDiff stuff essentially removes the time part of a DateTime.